# Object Oriented Inheritance in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, compilation, mips, code-generation

I'm a Computer Science student, currently taking a **Compilation** course, we have a project during the course to build a compiler in **IC** language which is a subset of Java language. I'm at the final part where I need to generate **MIPS** assembly without register allocation from the IR Tree.
I'm trying to understand how Object Instances are represented in **MIPS** assembly. I do know that I need to generate a **Virtual Function Table** for each object instance(which contains the addresses of the functions which are relevant for the instance).
**My question is:**
Do I need to do a similar table for the class fields, because fields are also inherited. And how would you suggest to do it?
Furthermore, I would be very grateful if anyone could give an example of how real **MIPS** assembly code would look like for object instances that inherit classes and fields.
**For example what would MIPS code look like for:**

```
class A{
    int x;
    void f(){}
}

class B extends A{
    int y;
    void g(){}

    void main(){
      A newObj = new B();
      newObj.f();
      newObj.x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fields can not be virtual, hence no need for a table. If you want to know how the asm looks like, use an existing compiler.

Comment: Note that a VMT is not needed *once per instance* - *Once per class* and all instances holding a pointer to there is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm addressing only this part of question:

> Furthermore, I would be very grateful if anyone could give an example of how real MIPS assembly code would look

I did rewrite your example into C++ in a way, that C++ compiler with few switches will not optimize it out totally and keep the fields and calls (if you wonder why `volatile` is used, and some other things, just to prevent compiler to produce assembly like `return value = 5, return`... C++ compilers tend to be a bit annoyingly good with optimizations, when you want just see some "example" code).

```cpp
class A {
  public:
    volatile int x;
    virtual void f(){
      ++x;
    }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    volatile int y;
    B(int i) {
      y = i;
      x = i-1;
    }
    virtual void f(){
      x += 2;
    }
    void g() {
      f();
      x += 3;
      ++y;
    }
};

int footest(int in) {
  B* obj = new B(in);
  A* obj_A_alias = obj;
  obj_A_alias->f();     // calling B::f(), because f is virtual
  obj->g();
  obj->f();
  obj->A::f();          // forcing A::f() call (on B instance)
  int result = obj->x + obj->y;
  delete obj;
  return result;
}
```

Now if you will put this into http://godbolt.org/ and set up compiler to MIPS gcc 5.4 with options `-O3 -std=c++11 -fno-loop-optimize -fno-inline`, you will get this output:

```lisp
$LFB0 = .
A::f():
$LVL0 = .
        lw      $2,4($4)
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,4($4)
        j       $31
        nop

$LFB7 = .
B::f():
$LVL1 = .
        lw      $2,4($4)
        addiu   $2,$2,2
        sw      $2,4($4)
        j       $31
        nop

$LFB3 = .
A::A():
$LVL2 = .
$LBB2 = .
        lui     $2,%hi(vtable for A+8)
        addiu   $2,$2,%lo(vtable for A+8)
        j       $31
        sw      $2,0($4)

$LBE2 = .
        A::A() = A::A()
$LFB5 = .
B::B(int):
$LVL3 = .
        addiu   $sp,$sp,-40
        sw      $17,32($sp)
        move    $17,$5
        sw      $31,36($sp)
        sw      $16,28($sp)
$LBB3 = .
        jal     A::A()
        move    $16,$4

$LVL4 = .
        addiu   $2,$17,-1
$LBE3 = .
        lw      $31,36($sp)
$LBB4 = .
        sw      $17,8($16)
        sw      $2,4($16)
        lui     $2,%hi(vtable for B+8)
$LBE4 = .
        lw      $17,32($sp)
$LVL5 = .
$LBB5 = .
        addiu   $2,$2,%lo(vtable for B+8)
        sw      $2,0($16)
$LBE5 = .
        lw      $16,28($sp)
$LVL6 = .
        j       $31
        addiu   $sp,$sp,40

        B::B(int) = B::B(int)
$LFB8 = .
B::g():
$LVL7 = .
        lw      $2,0($4)
        addiu   $sp,$sp,-32
        sw      $16,24($sp)
        sw      $31,28($sp)
        lw      $25,0($2)
        jalr    $25
        move    $16,$4

$LVL8 = .
        lw      $2,4($16)
        lw      $31,28($sp)
        addiu   $2,$2,3
        sw      $2,4($16)
        lw      $2,8($16)
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,8($16)
        lw      $16,24($sp)
$LVL9 = .
        j       $31
        addiu   $sp,$sp,32

$LFB9 = .
footest(int):
$LVL10 = .
        lui     $28,%hi(__gnu_local_gp)
        addiu   $sp,$sp,-32
        addiu   $28,$28,%lo(__gnu_local_gp)
        sw      $16,24($sp)
        move    $16,$4
$LVL11 = .
        sw      $31,28($sp)
        lw      $25,%call16(operator new(unsigned int))($28)
1:      jalr        $25
        li      $4,12                 # 0xc

$LVL12 = .
        move    $5,$16
        move    $16,$2
$LVL13 = .
        jal     B::B(int)
        move    $4,$2

$LVL14 = .
$LVL15 = .
        jal     B::f()
        move    $4,$16

$LVL16 = .
        jal     B::g()
        move    $4,$16

$LVL17 = .
        lw      $2,0($16)
        lw      $25,0($2)
        jalr    $25
        move    $4,$16

$LVL18 = .
        jal     A::f()
        move    $4,$16

$LVL19 = .
        move    $4,$16
        lw      $28,16($sp)
        lw      $2,4($16)
        lw      $16,8($16)
$LVL20 = .
        lw      $25,%call16(operator delete(void*))($28)
$LVL21 = .
1:      jalr        $25
        addu    $16,$2,$16

$LVL22 = .
        move    $2,$16
        lw      $31,28($sp)
        lw      $16,24($sp)
$LVL23 = .
        j       $31
        addiu   $sp,$sp,32

typeinfo name for A:
        .ascii  "1A\000"
typeinfo for A:
        .word   vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info+8
        .word   typeinfo name for A
typeinfo name for B:
        .ascii  "1B\000"
typeinfo for B:
        .word   vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info+8
        .word   typeinfo name for B
        .word   typeinfo for A
vtable for A:
        .word   0
        .word   typeinfo for A
        .word   A::f()
vtable for B:
        .word   0
        .word   typeinfo for B
        .word   B::f()
```

[Try it](https://godbolt.org/g/3zSHS9) on the actual site, so you will get also coloured hints which part of code belongs to which part of source (and there're also MIPS64 compilers, if that is your target platform).

---

EDIT: also you should probably try `-O0` option too, that output will be very likely lot more related to what you can reasonably achieve with one-student-alone project.

---

I'm not good enough in MIPS to explain you what's going on there, nor do I have time for that, but if you are producing compiler, you should understand it better than me.

The C++ source is demonstrating how virtual call is done (`$LVL17`), non virtual parent call (`$LVL18`), non virtual self call (`$LVL16`), and field values access (`$LVL19`).

Now keep in mind, this is professional optimized tool, so if you end with less optimal solution, it should be fine. Also keep in mind that compilation of Java and C++ differs a bit, in Java the end result is not as "static" as C++, so it may be you don't have enough info to optimize as aggressively as C++ does, like the non virtual function calls are simply hardcoded with target address, or fields too...

After all, if it's Java, you can't expect it to be optimal, for a managed runtime language it is sort of fine and together with high quality JIT compiler the basic code speed can be on par with C++, but once you are hit by inefficient Java data structures, C++ "swoooshs" along and beyond horizon.